# zlib.output_compression is set to On - ummm now what?

Tags: pagespeed

Apologies - I'm a beginner at this.

Running a PHP site on Apache / CentOS 6.4 (Final) Dedicated server.

I'd like to speed up my site.

zlib.output_compression is set to On

Not sure what I need to do now. And how I check the compression is working.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

This appears be all I need to do. :)

I used this website to check compression.
http://www.whatsmyip.org/http-compression-test